# Git : How to revert bulk commits on multiple repos

Tags: git, version-control

To update my multiple repos, I did:

```
git bulk fetch origin
git bulk pull origin master
```

Now it appears that some of the functionality which was working initially is not working now and so I want to revert back to previous state of my repos.

How can this be done ?

I tried doing git reset --soft commit id & git reset --hard commit id for one repos but it is not working.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Where does this `git bulk` command come from? It sounds like it could be quite useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`git reflog`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) to revert your repo to your old state.

You should see something along the lines of:

```
git reflog
bb3139b... HEAD@{0}: pull : Fast forward
01b34fa... HEAD@{1}: clone: from ...name..
```

Use a `git reset --hard` to reset the repo to the SHA1 read from the `git reflog`.

---

Note: Another way, instead of using `git-reflog` and copying SHA1 reference, is to use a [revision specification](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html): `master@{1}`, which is the previous position of master, `master@{"5 minutes ago"}`, or `master@{17:30}`.

Comment: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
` tried using in the directory where I have all my repos and am getting this error.

Comment: @Rachel: that is a command for *one* Git repo: you must be within that repo to run it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of second type ?

Comment: @Rachel: what is that `git bulk` command you use in your question? a script which execute a git command in all subdirectories?

Comment: yes. this command would run through all the subclasses and execute for each sub directory.

Comment: @Rachel: If you're really, really confident that all of the repos pulled something, you could do something like `git bulk reset --hard HEAD@{1}`, but if there's a repo which didn't pull any changes, that will not do what you want. It's going to be best for you to examine them one-by-one and make sure you're performing the reset you want.

Comment: Is there any way I have time information as to when the particular repo was modified and what files in there were modified with the modifications. I am sure that there has to be way to do this but just not sure of how this can be achieved.

Comment: @Jefromi: Yes. Actually right now am just doing it that way to get the information for each and every repo.

Comment: @Rachel: You can use `git log -g --name-status` to see the same thing as reflog, except with the full log information for each of the commits the reflog is pointing to. (`--name-status` gives you the names of all files it touched, with a flag to indicate whether they were added, deleted, modified, or renamed)